# Partial differential equation, finding the fist integrals

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Problem:** Find the surfaces passing through the line $y = x , z = 1$ and
orthogonal to the family of surfaces $x ^ { 2 } + y ^ { 2 } + z ^ { 2 } = c x$

The following is what I have done so far:

Let $f(x, y, z)=x+\frac{y^{2}}{x}+\frac{z^{2}}{x}=c$.

Let $z=g(x, y)$ be the surfaces orthogonal
to
the family of surfaces. We know that

$\nabla f \cdot N g=0$

$\Rightarrow\left\langle 1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}-\frac{z^{2}}{x^2}, \frac{2 y}{x}, \frac{2 z}{x}\right\rangle \cdot\left\langle z_x, z_x,-1\right\rangle=0$
$\left(\frac{x^{2}-y^{2}-x^{2}}{x^{2}}\right) z_{x}+\frac{2 y}{x} \cdot z_y-\frac{2 z}{x}=0$

multiply by $x^{2}$, and get
$\left(x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}\right) z_x+2 x y \cdot z_y=2 x z$

$\frac{d x}{x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}}=\frac{d y}{2 x y}=\frac{d z}{2 z x}$

From $\quad\quad \frac{d y}{2 x y}=\frac{d z}{2 z x}, \quad \frac{d y}{y}=\frac{d z}{z}=> \quad \ln y=\ln z+C$

$\Rightarrow \quad \frac{y}{z}=\theta_{1}(x, y, z)$

However, I stuck at finding the second first integral, $\theta_2$. I'm open to any help.